# How can I pass along runtime arguments to sub components using Typhoon?

Tags: objective-c, typhoon

Let's say I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar`. I can construct a `Bar` independently of `Foo`, but `Foo` needs a `Bar`. In Typhoon I define these two components and use them in my applicaiton however at runtime when constructing a `Foo` the `barId` that I pass in appears to be passed down to the other `Bar` component as a `<TyphoonInjectionByRuntimeArgument: 0x15ea4670, type=Undifined>` and not the `NSString` that I passed in.

I'm probably doing it wrong.

What should I do differently?

```
@implementation Assembly

-(Foo *)fooWithFooId:(NSString *)fooId andBarId:(NSString *)barId {
  return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[Foo class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {
    [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithFooId:andBar:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
        [initializer injectParameterWith:fooId];
        [initializer injectParameterWith:[self barWithId:barId]];
    }];
  }];
}

-(Bar *)barWithBarId:(NSString *)barId {
  return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[Bar class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {
    [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithBarId:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
      [initializer injectParameterWith:barId];
    }];
  }];
}

@end

////////

@implementation Foo

-(instancetype) initWithFooId:(NSString *)fooId andBar:(Bar *)bar
{
  self = [super init];
  self.fooId = fooId;
  self.bar = bar;
  return self;
}

@end

@implementation Bar

-(instancetype) initWithBarId:(NSString *)barId
{
  self = [super init];
  self.barId = barId;
  return self;
}

@end
```

### Update:

After further review the issue appeared to be caused by using the runtime argument inside the definition to build another parameter for another definition. See the usage of `NSString` below:

```
@implementation Assembly

-(Foo *)fooWithFooId:(NSString *)fooId andBazId:(NSString *)bazId {
  return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[Foo class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {
    [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithFooId:andBaz:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
        [initializer injectParameterWith:fooId];
        [initializer injectParameterWith:[self bazWithPathToBaz:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/some/path/to/baz/%@", bazId]]];
    }];
  }];
}

-(Baz *)bazWithPathToBaz:(NSString *)bazPath {
  return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[Baz class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {
    [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithBazPath:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
      [initializer injectParameterWith:bazPath];
    }];
  }];
}

@end
```

When called the path passed into the initializer would come be `"/some/path/to/baz/<TyphoonInjectionByRuntimeArgument: 0x15ea4670, type=Undifined>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you obtaining your built instance of `Foo`? Your assembly code above looks OK, but keep in mind the following:

- **Build-time:** An assembly returns instances of `TyphoonDefinition`. Typhoon instruments this assembly to collect the information that it needs to return built instances at runtime. This includes injecting runtime arguments with proxies (instances of `TyphoonInjectionByRuntimeArgument`).
- **Run-time:** The assembly now returns built components according to the rules defined in the definitions. (Its actually a proxy pointing at a `TyphoonComponentFactory`).

After creating one ore more assemblies, the following is required to have the assembly return a built component:

```
- (void)testFoobar
{
    //Pass in a not-built assembly to TyphoonComponentFactory
    TyphoonComponentFactory *factory =
        [TyphoonBlockComponentFactory factoryWithAssemblies:@[[Assembly assembly]]]; 

    //Now we have a built assembly
    Assembly *builtAssembly = (Assembly*) factory;

    Foo *builtFoo = [builtAssembly fooWithFooId:@"1234" andBarId:@"5678"];
    NSLog(@"%@", builtFoo);
}
```

**Result:** `<Foo: self.fooId=1234, self.bar=<Bar: self.barId=5678>>`

(or in the case of an app you could use plist-integration to bootstrap Typhoon and inject the app delegate. Note that you can inject the assembly itself into any component, either as a `TyphoonComponentFactory` or posing as one of your assembly interfaces. This is useful to transition from one object-graph (eg view controller) to another.)

**Edit:**

Although it wasn't the original intention, in most cases you can also use run-time arguments from within an assembly, and we now do this in our own apps. For example:

```
- (OfferManager *)offerManager
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[OfferManager class] 
        configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithEngine:) 
            parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {

            [initializer injectParameterWith:
                [self engineWithPollingInterval:@120 cacheExpire:@3600]];
        }];
    }];
}
```

. . but currently its not possible to create a top-level definition that is the result of another definition with runtime arguments. Example:

```
- (Engine*) preConfiguredEngine {
    return [self engineWithPollingInterval:@120 cacheExpire:@3600];
}
```

. . the reason is fairly simple, and if you need this we can look at it.

Comment: Also note that earlier versions of Typhoon did not propagate runtime arguments to children. Are you on the latest 2.3.2?

Comment: Yes we are on the latest. I'm noticing now that our problem may have been in our understanding of the way passing in arguments worked at runtime. We were building a string with `NSString stringWithFormat` inside the method definition which wasn't being executed at runtime but I guess was being constructed earlier in the life of the component.

Comment: In most cases you can do this - use runtime arguments within an assembly. But you currently can't from a top level definition. (See edit). Do you need this? If you raise an issue we can look at it.

Comment: @RyanMontgomery See edit. If I understand correctly what you want to do could be supported within hours.

Comment: I just updated the question to include an update with a better explanation. It would be nice to do something as I describe. Our intention was to push the dependencies out to the configuration. We also had an example that failed for similar reasons when trying to build and pass in an `NSPredicate`. It suffered the same issue.

Comment: Ah I see. Unfortunately that's not possible with the runtime args feature. You'd have to create a custom factory class, and inject the assembly into it. This class could then pull things from the assembly and mix them with things provided at runtime. A) you can supply runtime args at runtime b) you can hard-code them in the assembly interface like in the 'edit' part of my answer above . . But you can't take a runtime argument, manipulate it and then pass it to something else. Neither can you invoke methods on s runtime arg within the assembly interface.

Comment: Yep. We came to the same conclusion. Thanks for your prompt response.